# casting a string to a GUID does not give right result

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-propertytree

In my program, I need to read a guid value stored in a xml file. Here is how xml file looks like.

```
<data>
 <id>3AAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-2EEEEEEEEEEE</id>
</data>
```

My program needs to read this value in a GUID type variable. Below is what I have for this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib") 
int main()
{
    pt::ptree tree;
    std::string filename = "data.xml";

    pt::read_xml(filename, tree);

    std::string idStr = tree.get<std::string>("data.id");
    std::cout << "id as string = " << idStr << std::endl;
    GUID idAsGuid;

    auto res = UuidFromStringW((RPC_WSTR)idStr.c_str(), &idAsGuid);
    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        std::wcerr << L"Conversion failed with error: 0x" << std::hex << res << std::endl;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

The variable **idStr** gets the correct values but **idAsGuid** variable (that is a GUID type) gets incorrect values (something like CCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCCC). What am I diong wrong here?

Comment: A note about terminology: There's no *casting* being done here.

Comment: can you point out what casting I need to do?

Comment: You use a function to parse and make sense of some input string. Casting is e.g. converting a character to an integer as in `static_cast<int>('a')`.

Comment: Can you add an answer with example? I have been trying to use reinterpret_cast without any luck

Comment: Looks like you’re casting a (pointer to a) ”narrow” string to a (pointer to a) ”wide” string. Use the proper function instead (that ends with ’A’, not ’W’) or convert — not cast — your input.

Comment: @molbdnilo Can you add any answer with correct code please? I have been trying with various flavors of A, W without any luck.

Comment: @BKS Various flavours? there's only two flavours `UuidFromStringW` and `UuidFromStringA` and the second one is the correct one, and remove your cast `(RPC_WSTR)`, you don't need it.

Comment: @john With your suggestion, I get following compilation error. RPC_STATUS UuidFromStringA(RPC_CSTR,UUID *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char* ' to 'RPC_CSTR'
note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: @BKS seems it more complicated that I realised. I think you've picked the wrong API call to convert a string to a GUID. It seems that RPC strings are some complex thing that I don't really understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char*` pointer, which you are type-casting to `RPC_WSTR`, aka **non-const** `unsigned short*`.  That cast will never work.  At the very least, you need to *convert* the `std::string` to a UTF-16 encoded `std::wstring` first, eg:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring widStr = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>{}.from_bytes(idStr);

auto res = UuidFromStringW(reinterpret_cast<RPC_WSTR>(const_cast<wchar_t*>(widStr.c_str())), &idAsGuid);
// or:
// auto res = UuidFromStringW(reinterpret_cast<RPC_WSTR>(&widStr[0]), &idAsGuid);
```

Otherwise, use `UuidFromStringA()` instead, but note that `RPC_CSTR` is defined as a **non-const** `unsigned char*`, so you still need similar casting:

```
auto res = UuidFromStringA(reinterpret_cast<RPC_CSTR>(const_cast<char*>(idStr.c_str())), &idAsGuid);
// or:
// auto res = UuidFromStringA(reinterpret_cast<RPC_CSTR>(&idStr[0]), &idAsGuid);
```

With that said, consider using `GUIDFromStringA()` instead, which doesn't require any conversion or casting:

```
auto res = GUIDFromStringA(idStr.c_str(), &idAsGuid);
```

Though, you might have to add braces to the guid string:

```
auto res = GUIDFromStringA(("{" + idStr + "}").c_str(), &idAsGuid);
```

Otherwise, just parse the guid string manually, such as with `std::istringstream`, `std::regex`, `std::sscanf()`, etc.